# Google maps geometry controls identify coordinates array

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

in this [example](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/examples/test.html) on [geometry.js](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/src/geometrycontrols.js) page i found saveData function that save "info" to arrays and JSON data format (not working), if I  alert(record.type); i get "point" or "polilyne" according th object i've clicked, if i alert record.title output the title very right, but when i alert record.coordinates the output is undifined...

i just need to identify the "place" whre are saved the coordinates...

thanks,
regards

Comment: This looks like a v2 question.  Your tag is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to your page? As for where the geometries are stored, each control added to the page (markers, lines, polygons) has its own storage array, for example from the polygoncontrol.js

```
me.storage = [/*array of GeometryControls#beans#Geometry*/]
```

and if you look at the defintion of the GeometryControls#beans, you'd see

```
Geometry:function(p){

    this.type = p.type;

    this.geometry = p.geometry;

    this.title = p.title || ["",""];

    this.description = p.description || ["",""];

  }
```

the actual coordinates are serialized right in the GeometryControls.prototype.saveData

```
 //determine geometry type, and copy geometry appropriately

    if(record.type === "point"){

      recordJSON.coordinates.push({lat:record.geometry.getLatLng().lat(),lng:record.geometry.getLatLng().lng()});

    } else {

      var vertex;

      for(var i=0;i<record.geometry.getVertexCount();i++){

        vertex = record.geometry.getVertex(i);

        recordJSON.coordinates.push({lat:vertex.lat(),lng:vertex.lng()});

      }

    }
```